# How to remove list from inside a dictionary and make it list of tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I have a variable that is a list which has tuples inside of that like so:

```
variable = [{'email':['1@1.com']},{'email':['2@2.com']}]
```

How do I make the variable so it is a list of tuples like so?:

```
variable = [{'email':'1@1.com'},{'email':'2@2.com'}]
```

I have tried removing the characters like so:

```
variable.remove('[')
```

But I get syntax error

> TypeError: descriptor 'remove' requires a 'list' object but received a
>   'str'

Edit:

I am using jmespath library to crawl a json response.

```
import jmespath

path_to_data = jmespath.search("key1[*].key2[].key3.{email:[?type=='EMAIL'].value}",data_source)




path_to_data = [{'email':['1@1.com']},{'email':['2@2.com']}]
```

Jmespath is creating the listobject.

Comment: The syntax of your first example is fubar on the first entry in the list - please edit your question to show syntax that actually works. AND please edit the code you have written to try solve this problem into your question - StackOverflow is not a code writing service. AND if you haven't tried to write some code to solve this, well: do it.

Comment: @barny I added what I tried and it is not fubar that is exactly how it looks.

Comment: @jpp I removed replaced the comma with colon, please try now.

Comment: Based on the error message, it seems like your variables might actually be strings (instead of the lists you are showing in your question).

Comment: @benvc when I check my variable it says list in spyder, and within each list is another list, do you still think variable?

Comment: @jpp do you think the list is really a string?

Comment: Best thing to do would be to edit your question with the actual section of your code that is causing the issue so that we can see how you are initializing your `variable` variable in the first place and then what, if anything, is taking place from there until you attempt `variable.remove('[')`.

Comment: @benvc I will add in what is messing me up

Comment: Did this code solves your issue ? `[{k: v[0]} for elm in variable for k, v in elm.items()]`

Comment: @jpp I added in the code

Comment: @ChihebNexus that worked!

Comment: @jpp I ran your line and got `<class 'list'>`

Comment: @RustyShackleford it's not fubar now because you editied the first example so it really is a dictionary! There is ZERO point posting pseudocode that you can't execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically, to solve your issue you can do:

```
variable = [{'email':['1@1.com']},{'email':['2@2.com']}]
output = [{k: v[0]} for elm in variable for k, v in elm.items()]
print(output)

[{'email': '1@1.com'}, {'email': '2@2.com'}]
```